# Database design for a product-configurator

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have been asked by a customer to develop a "product configurator", and i need some inputs on how to handle the DB part of the project.

Each product can have a subset of different precreated attributes.
The minimum is 1 attribute, but there is no maximum.

Some attributes have dependencies/relationships with other attributes.
Eg. If the product is a chair, you need to choose the material (wood, plastic, metal), and you need to choose which type of legs the chair shoud have.
If the Product is a cabinet, you still need to choose a material, but instead of legs there will be different doors to choose from etc.

Each of these attributes might have subattributes. Eg. the door has a color, a size and a doorhandle.
Then the door handle has a material, a type and so on.

This ultimatly ends up in a multi-layered attribute-tree.

By itself this isnt too complicated to code, however the customer wants to be able to manage (Create, update and delete) all products, attributes and relationships between attributes, within the webapp.

So coding the relationship-part isn't a viable solution.

I have gone with a EAV model to facilitate the "potential unlimited" amount of attributes each product can have.
But i am struggling to figure out how to go about the "attribute relationships".

A simplified version of my DB design looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If each product could subscribe to groups of attributes that is legal. Then each attribute belongs to a group like "wood group".

Then the user could set the groups of attributes against a product that should need to be answered to configure a product.

With regards managing a tree, you could use a column type of hierarchyid . Or construct an outline string as key field.

An outline for example

```
1.
1.1.
1.1.1.
1.2.
2.
2.1.
```